# trying to solve $2^x \equiv 9 \pmod{13}$

Tags: logarithms

I'm trying to solve

$$ 2^x \equiv 9 \pmod{13} $$

so I tried to define all numbers for $x$ which match this requirement and I came up with this equation:

$$ \sqrt{\sin(((x)-13/2-9)*\pi/13)^2} $$

now i just want numbers 2^x and i changed it to

$$ \sqrt{\sin(((2^x)-13/2-9)*\pi/13)^2} = 1 $$

this part seems to work, i come to

$${pi = pi, x = ln(-1/2*(-31*pi+13*Pi)/pi)/ln(2)}, {pi = pi, x = ln(1/2*(31*pi+13*Pi)/pi)/ln(2)}$$

and

$$ 2^(1.442695041*ln(-.5000000000*(-31.*pi+40.84070450)/pi)) = 9.00000000099 $$

the second requirement is that $x$ is an integer, I defined it by this equation

$$ \sqrt{\sin((x+1/2)*\pi)^2}=1 $$

but when I try to solve this system of equations with maple, I don't get an answer, why?

Comment: How did you come up with these equations?

Comment: i plotted them and thought it looks good

Comment: Are you familiar with modular arithmetic?

Comment: Find the minimal case that $2^d=0$ and test cases below that above zero. The solutions are the the solutions you found plus integer multiples of $d$.

Comment: Note that $2^d\equiv0\pmod{13}$ has no (integer) solutions. Do you mean $2^d\equiv1\pmod{13}$?

Comment: @Pax: There are infinitely many solutions, they are the integers of the form $8+12k$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: why not $9+13k$ ?

Comment: did nobody try to follow my thoughts?

Comment: It's not that no one tried to follow them, it's that, while they work, there are much, much simpler ways to do this. Not everything has to be a function on the real numbers.

Comment: yes but the other ways are mostly trial and error

Answer (score 7):

The powers of $2$ mod $13$ are:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
n&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12\\
\hline
2^n\text{ mod }13&1&2&4&8&3&6&12&11&9&5&10&7&1
\end{array}
$$
Note that this repeats for $n$ mod $12$. Therefore,
$$
n\equiv8\pmod{12}\implies2^n\equiv9\pmod{13}
$$

---

Here are plots of the functions you are using:

$\hspace{8mm}$[image]

Both curves do seem to meet at $x=8$; however, tangents to solutions are often less stable for automated solvers. A small amount of error can keep a solution from being found. This is most likely why Maple is having trouble finding solutions. The frequecy of the green function get higher as $x$ gets larger, while the frequency of the red function stays constant. This also adds to the numerical instability.

---

A more stable attempt would be to use
$$
\sin((2^x-9)\pi/13)=0
$$
and
$$
\sin(x\pi/13)=0
$$
[image]

However, the frequency of the green function becomes so great at the next solution ($x=20$), that numerical solution become sensitive to small errors because of that.

Comment: i know the brute force way... the question was what's wrong with my equations?

Comment: The question is: What's right about them? How do you justify them?

Comment: you can plot them... the maximum points of the first equation are the solutions for x mod 13=9

Comment: Is there a more general theorem at use here to show that $n \equiv a \space \left( \text{mod } b \right)$ implies $2^n \equiv c \space \left( \text{mod } d \right)$?

Comment: @Ryan: Yes. If $n\equiv a\pmod{\phi(13)}$, then $2^n\equiv2^a\pmod{13}$

Comment: hm and why isn't there a solution for this system of equations? $sin((2^x-9)*Pi/13)=sin(x*Pi)$ is no problem, but the combination with $sin(x*Pi)=0$ ...

Comment: @wutzebaer: My guess is that it is because you are trying to find the intersection of three curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$. That is fraught with trouble if there is *any* error.

Answer (score 1):

I used another method, using less intelligence than Mark Bennet's answer but still a little quicker than checking all the powers until the answer appears.  Checking powers of 2 modulo 13, I got 2, 4, 8, 3, 6, 12.  Since $2^6\equiv 12\equiv-1$ and $2^2=4$, it follows that $2^{6+2}\equiv4\cdot(-1)\equiv 9$ so one solution is 6+2, i.e., 8.

To get all the solutions, use the fact that powers of 2 (or of anything) repeat after 12 steps, by Fermat's little theorem.  The powers of 2 don't repeat after any proper divisor of 2 many steps (because none of the 2, 4, 8, 3, 6, 12 computed above are 1), so all the solutions are $8+12k$ for arbitrary natural numbers $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $2^4=16 \equiv 3 \mod 13$ so that $2^8=(2^4)^2\equiv (3)^2=9 \mod 13$

Comment: this only works if i already know that the result is 8

Comment: @wutzebaer I didn't know what the answer was, and I have written down how I worked it out. If I didn't spot a short cut, I could compute all the powers of $2$ modulo $13$: $2^0=1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 6, 12, 11, 9$ until I got to $9$. It is not guaranteed that there will be a solution, but since we know from Fermat that $2^{12} \equiv 1$ we know that we have a finite task - and in fact when $2^4$ and $2^6$ turn out not to be $1$ we know that $2$ is a primitive root mod 13, and there will be a solution.

Comment: means i just need to find an $2^x$ whichs result is an divider of the wanted result?